# AWS API Gateway - Lambda Proxy not turning on via CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am using `CloudFormation` to create an API in API Gateway. Each one of my endpoints points to a Lambda function. I need to turn on "Lambda Proxy integration" for each endpoint.

Here's a snippet from my `CloudFormation` template:

```yaml
method1:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
    Properties: 
        ApiKeyRequired: true
        AuthorizationType: None 
        HttpMethod: POST
        Integration:
            Type: AWS_PROXY
            IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
            IntegrationResponses:
                - ResponseTemplates:
                    application/json: Empty
                StatusCode: 200
            Uri: 
                Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${ProjectName}-${Environment}-method1'
        MethodResponses:
            - ResponseModels:
                application/json: Empty
            StatusCode: 200
        RequestValidatorId: !Ref validateBodyValidator
        ResourceId: !Ref method1Resource
        RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
```

I have set my integration type as `AWS_PROXY`. When I run this template, everything seems like. I get the following result:

[image]
[image]

As you see, `Use Lambda Proxy integration` option is shown as selected.
However, when I make the API call, I get the following error.

```json
[
    "Internal Server Error"
]
```

After a day of trying to find the issue, here's what I found:

**If I uncheck the `Use Lambda Proxy integration` option, re-check it, and deploy - it starts working.**

It's almost like - it looks selected but it's not selected. I have to manually uncheck and recheck for EVERY method.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you add a lambda permission to allow API Gateway to invoke Lambda? If you check the option in AWS GUI it might add that permission for you but it doesn't come out of the box if you didn't specify it in you cloudformation.

Comment: ah! that sounds like a very good possibility. I will take a look.Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, thanks to [congbaoguier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573573/congbaoguier) for your comment above.

I added the `Method1Permission` section in the following template where I create my Lambda function:

```yaml
Method1:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    DependsOn:
        - Method1Role
        - Method1Policy
    Properties:
        Role: !GetAtt Method1Role.Arn 
        Code:
            S3Bucket: !ImportValue sharedinf-cp-lambdabucketname
            S3Key: Method1.jar
    Handler: com.companyname.projectname.methodname::handleRequest
    Runtime: "java8"
    Timeout: "15"
    MemorySize: "512"

Method1Permission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
    FunctionName: !GetAtt 
        - Method1
        - Arn
    Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
    Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

This allowed API gateway to access my Lambda function.